# MS SQL DBCC CHECKDB page ID (1:xxx) contains an incorrect page ID

Tags: sql-server, repair, dbcc

Fistly, yes I'm aware that there are two options 1) is to restore or 2) run DBCC with allow data loss. But I'd like to understand what exactly is corrupted and what possible data loss could be. From DBCC CHECKDB these are the only errors

---

> Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0, index ID
>   -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page ID (1:24694884) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The
>   PageId in the page header = (0:0). Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0
>   (type Unknown), page ID (1:24694885) contains an incorrect page ID in
>   its page header. The PageId in the page header = (0:0). Msg 8909,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1,
>   partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page ID (1:24694886)
>   contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the
>   page header = (0:0). Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error:
>   Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type
>   Unknown), page ID (1:24694887) contains an incorrect page ID in its
>   page header. The PageId in the page header = (0:0). Msg 8939, Level
>   16, State 5, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition
>   ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (1:24694888). Test
>   (m_headerVersion == HEADER_7_0) failed. Values are 0 and 1. Msg 8939,
>   Level 16, State 6, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1,
>   partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (1:24694888).
>   Test ((m_type >= DATA_PAGE && m_type <= UNDOFILE_HEADER_PAGE) ||
>   (m_type == UNKNOWN_PAGE && level == BASIC_HEADER)) failed. Values are
>   0 and 0. Msg 8939, Level 16, State 7, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0,
>   index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page
>   (1:24694888). Test (m_freeData >= PageHeaderOverhead () && m_freeData
>   <= (UINT)PAGESIZE - m_slotCnt * sizeof (Slot)) failed. Values are 0
>   and 8192. Service Broker Msg 9675, State 1: Message Types analyzed:
>   14. Service Broker Msg 9676, State 1: Service Contracts analyzed: 6. Service Broker Msg 9667, State 1: Services analyzed: 3. Service Broker
>   Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3. Service Broker Msg
>   9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0. Service Broker Msg
>   9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0. Service Broker Msg
>   9670, State 1: Remote Service Bindings analyzed: 0. Service Broker Msg
>   9605, State 1: Conversation Priorities analyzed: 0. CHECKDB found 0
>   allocation errors and 7 consistency errors not associated with any
>   single object.

---

### then fine and then

> Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102,
>   index ID 10, partition ID 72057774144880640, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266253312 (type In-row data). Page (1:2720992) is missing a
>   reference from previous page (1:24661767). Possible chain linkage
>   problem. Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID
>   1880468102, index ID 13, partition ID 72057774145011712, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266384384 (type In-row data). Page (1:17132104) is missing a
>   reference from previous page (1:24694888). Possible chain linkage
>   problem. Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1 Table error: Object ID
>   1880468102, index ID 10, partition ID 72057774144880640, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266253312 (type In-row data), page (1:24661767). Test (IS_OFF
>   (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -4. Msg 8928,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Object ID 1880468102, index ID 10, partition
>   ID 72057774144880640, alloc unit ID 72057774266253312 (type In-row
>   data): Page (1:24661767) could not be processed.  See other errors for
>   details. Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID
>   1880468102, index ID 10, partition ID 72057774144880640, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266253312 (type In-row data). Page (1:24661767) was not seen
>   in the scan although its parent (1:2927950) and previous (1:11145041)
>   refer to it. Check any previous errors. Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98,
>   Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057774144749568, alloc unit ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data),
>   page (1:24694883). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed.
>   Values are 133129 and -4. Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Object
>   ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit
>   ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data): Page (1:24694883) could not
>   be processed.  See other errors for details. Msg 8928, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 Object ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057774144749568, alloc unit ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data):
>   Page (1:24694884) could not be processed.  See other errors for
>   details. Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Object ID 1880468102,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266056704 (type In-row data): Page (1:24694885) could not be
>   processed.  See other errors for details. Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Object ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057774144749568, alloc unit ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data):
>   Page (1:24694886) could not be processed.  See other errors for
>   details. Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Object ID 1880468102,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266056704 (type In-row data): Page (1:24694887) could not be
>   processed.  See other errors for details. Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Object ID 1880468102, index ID 13, partition ID
>   72057774145011712, alloc unit ID 72057774266384384 (type In-row data):
>   Page (1:24694888) could not be processed.  See other errors for
>   details. Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID
>   1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266056704 (type In-row data). Page (1:24694883) was not seen
>   in the scan although its parent (1:24696205) and previous (1:24694882)
>   refer to it. Check any previous errors. Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057774144749568, alloc unit ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data).
>   Index node page (1:24696205), slot 57 refers to child page
>   (1:24694884) and previous child (1:24694883), but they were not
>   encountered. Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object
>   ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit
>   ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:24696205),
>   slot 58 refers to child page (1:24694885) and previous child
>   (1:24694884), but they were not encountered. Msg 8980, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057774144749568, alloc unit ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data).
>   Index node page (1:24696205), slot 59 refers to child page
>   (1:24694886) and previous child (1:24694885), but they were not
>   encountered. Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object
>   ID 1880468102, index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit
>   ID 72057774266056704 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:24696205),
>   slot 60 refers to child page (1:24694887) and previous child
>   (1:24694886), but they were not encountered. Msg 8976, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102, index ID 13, partition ID
>   72057774145011712, alloc unit ID 72057774266384384 (type In-row data).
>   Page (1:1) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:2934717)
>   and previous (1:17132103) refer to it. Check any previous errors. Msg
>   8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 1880468102,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057774144749568, alloc unit ID
>   72057774266056704 (type In-row data). Page (1:24694920) is missing a
>   reference from previous page (1:24694887). Possible chain linkage
>   problem. DBCC results for 'tb_ExternSale'. There are 96199140 rows in
>   2665693 pages for object "tb_ExternSale". CHECKDB found 0 allocation
>   errors and 19 consistency errors in table 'tb_ExternSale' (object ID
>   1880468102).

--

The pages from first part refer to the same pages with tb_ExternSale table having issues. Is it correct to assume that tb_ExternSale data is the only one that has data etc. corruption? and is it possible to identify rows?

Thanks
Pavel

Comment: Have you checked Paul Randals blogpost? It might help you figure out what pages are damaged, and thus maybe figure out which data is affected. 

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-using-dbcc-page-to-find-what-repair-will-delete/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, reading now. I'm actually reading through his articles and I think missed this one.